# Swift WKWebview load image from local bundle

Tags: swift, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration, custom-scheme-url

I have created a Bundle `Images.bundle` which contains some images and I'm creating programmatically an HTML which displays the image pointing to the URL of the bundle image:

```
 //Here I simply add the basic HTML body tags... skipping this part
  if let imageURL: URL = ImageUtils.getMapUrlFromBundle(mapId) {

     htmlString += """
        <image
            width=\"\(imageURL.size.width)\"
            height=\"\(imageURL.size.height)\"
            href="\(imageURL)\">
        </image>
    """
```

Then loading this htmlString in the WKWebView:

`webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)`

The problem is that the imageURL is not being recognized by the WKWebview:

`href="file:///Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A12DFC-6401-3A42-LAS9-FLK129FDH/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/O12K3213-4ASD-123/Test.app/Images.bundle/test.webp"`

I've read that using some custom scheme is the way to go but I'm new to iOS and I don't know exactly how to do this, any hint?

EDIT: Base64 conversion of the image is not a valid option.

Comment: @timbretimbre two of the 3 answers use base 64, the other one is using Objective C

Comment: so what that it's in objective C? still a valid and very good solution. If you have trouble reading it, use swiftify